# My popup only displays the information for the first row in mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am super new to php and SQL and I am having trouble displaying my SQL data within a HTML/JS popup. I have successfully been able to produce each of my assignmentName's as buttons on my page, but when I click on the button the "content" shown for each one is the same (and it is the data linked with my first assignmentName). I want the "content" for each popup to correspond correctly to each of the assignmentName's.

Here is the php code, grateful for any answers:

```
$sql = "SELECT dueDate, assignmentName, className 
        FROM assignments 
            INNER JOIN classes ON assignments.class = classes.id 
        ORDER BY DATE(dueDate)";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "Assignments";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<div class="popup" id="popup-1">';
                echo '<div class="overlay"></div>';
                echo '<div class = "content">' . $row['dueDate'] . $row['className'] . '</div>';
                echo '<div class="close-btn content" onclick="togglePopup()">&times;</div>';
                echo '<div class = "btn-group">' . '<button onclick="togglePopup()">' . $row['assignmentName'] . '</button>' . '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Never a good idea to use the same `id` attribute/value inside a loop. `id`s need to be unique in a document. What would `togglePopup()` do?

Comment: `function togglePopup(){
 document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");
  } ` that is what the function does

Comment: Also which id are you referring to ? popup-1?

Comment: `id="popup-1"` - make this one _unique_ (`id="popup-2"`, `id="popup-3"` etc) and adjust your javascript accordingly